# Trying to create little program in python, having some issues. (New to coding)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm creating a code that will allow for my mouse pointer to go in circles, only when I'm holding down shift on my keyboard.

```
pyautogui.dragTo(100, 100, duration=0.25)
pyautogui.dragTo(200, 100, duration=0.25)
pyautogui.dragTo(200, 200, duration=0.25)
pyautogui.dragTo(100, 200, duration=0.25)
```

only when I'm holding shift down.

Would it be best to create a variable in which the value is 1 only when shift is held, then set my loop to only run when the value is 1? Or not even create a variable in general?

Not sure how to translate that into a if/loop statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no loop here to speak of from my current understanding. It may be helpful to start with some more basic python scripts before you work with guis and the like. As for the question itself, you can directly check if the shift key is held down and then move the mouse pointer when that happens. It seems you are not allowing it but rather causing the circling to happen, in which case the relevant loop would be something like

```
while True:
 if shift key held:
  pyautogui. etc...
```

Comment: I was referencing "pyautogui.dragTo(100, 100, duration=0.25)
pyautogui.dragTo(200, 100, duration=0.25)
pyautogui.dragTo(200, 200, duration=0.25)
pyautogui.dragTo(100, 200, duration=0.25)" as a section of my code that was suppose to be in a loop. But yes that was the loop I was talking about! Thank you very much.

Comment: GUI is a very ambitious first thing to start with in a new language.

Comment: What would you recommend I focused on for being new to python? I've messed around with java for a couple months but lost interest after a while. Really been wanting to go ahead and learn everything about C, C#, C++ (Already know some of the basic concepts) but I want to be proficient in something like python first.

Comment: I would say that C is probably one of the worst languages to start with if you've having trouble keeping interest since there are so many things you will get bogged down on, and it's difficult to make meaningful progress for a bit of time. If you want to get more familiar with algorithms, check out Project Euler or something like HackerRank. If you're more interested in doing something and figuring it out later, closely follow a pygame tutorial and make sure you understand everything that's going on.

Comment: Would you recommend that I just got proficient in python before trying to mess with someone like c#? It's not that I couldn't understand java, I just knew how limited it can be.. well, not to my interests at least. Looking for something more powerful and objective based

Comment: Any of these languages is powerful enough